# Handling error in http.get()

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, error-handling

I'm trying to access an endpoint URL by using the following code

```
this.http.get<IApiResponse>(this.endpointURL, {headers: headers, params: params}).subscribe(
            (response:IApiResponse) => {         
              // handle response
            },
            error => {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
```

This method works, as expected. But when my device running this app has no internet connection I get the following output in the chromium console:

```
GET https://endpoint/file.php?someParams net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

and

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error:ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message:"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name:"HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status:0
statusText:"Unknown Error"
url:null
__proto__:HttpResponseBase
```

The second output seems to be the one from the `console.log(error);`, but this one gives me no useful information (`"Unknown Error"`). And I don't know where the first error message comes from (it's background is red in the console), but that's the one that contains actually useful information and I can't access it.

How can I determine whats wrong in the

```
error => {

}
```

scope?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';


(error: Response) => {
   const text = error.text();
   console.log(text);
});
```

But I guess this will still throw "Unknown Error".

From my point of view the message

```
GET https://endpoint/file.php?someParams net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

derives from the browser itself and can't be accessed by Angular.

Comment: Yeah you can assume that an error with status 0 is not coming from the server, so it's likely a connectivity error.